# Usage of superlative in the context of more than one item

Tags: grammar, superlative-degree

Can we use superlative when we are talking about 2 or more items? I'm not quite sure about that since the rule says: "Superlative adjectives are used to describe **an object** which is at the upper or lower limit of a quality".

I wanted to figure out this before talking to my student who wrote the following sentence:"Only a few *games* are *the most popular* in the world".

Comment: Yes: 'The best things in life are free'. Wherever you got your 'rule' from, send it back and get the correct version (though arguably it's incomplete, not totally erroneous). However, using a quantified expression directly with the superlative set ("Only a few games are the most popular in the world"; "Many/few paintings are the most expensive"; "A dozen breeds are the fiercest") doesn't sound right at all. Contrast "These games are the most popular in the world"; "Di Maggio's paintings are the most expensive"; "A dozen breeds of dog, listed in Doggypedia, are considered to be the fiercest".

Comment: @Edwin is correct. It's a good example of how well-meaning rules can confuse people when they claim to cover all uses. There are **always** exceptions, usually due to overgeneralization on the part of the rule-writer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is based unfortunately on a badly-worded law; I would opt for [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/superlative)'s definition:

> The form of an adjective or adverb that is used to indicate the greatest degree of a particular quality

The following examples (from [this](https://www.englishforums.com/English/SuperlativeAndPlural/zrlmv/post.htm) thread) are all cases in which plural objects are used with superlatives:

> *Basketball players are among the tallest men in the world.*
>   *She is one of the richest women in the world*

Comment: I really appreciate your prompt answer! Thank you.

Comment: @TanyaSolovianchyk You're welcome! If you want to accept or up-vote the answer, it will show that you have agreed with this answer and it stops the question from being bumped up as if it were unanswered.